# identify valid SVG using PHP

Tags: php, svg, graphicsmagick

I need to check an upload for file type **SVG**. Unfortunately, there's no `IMAGETYPE_SVG` and `finfo_file` does not work on my machine. How can I make sure the upload is valid? However, I do have access to **GraphicsMagick** via `system()`

Comment: To what level? SVG files are XML so would checking for a valid XML file be enough?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried isValid from XMLReader, but it returns true, although I have used a PNG instead of SVG. This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using GraphicsMagick:

```
$valid = FALSE;
@exec("gm identify +ping filename", $result);
if (is_array($result)) {
    if (in_array("MVG", explode(" ", implode(" ", $result))) || in_array("SVG", explode(" ", implode(" ", $result)))) $valid = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You would just check if it is just .svg

```
$path = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
//gets extension
$e = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($e == "svg"){
//it is svg
}else{
//not svg 
}
```

Comment: of course I will not use this, anyone can name any file .svg